# Magento 2 : How to get postcode from selected shipping addresses in checkout page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout-page

How we can get the value of postcode from selected shipping addresses on checkout page if a customer has multiple addresses?

[image]

Comment: $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this first you have to override core functionality in your custom module
Go to Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service' : 
            'NameSpace_ModuleName/js/model/shipping-service'      
        }
  }
};
```

and Go to Namespace/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-service.js

```
/*global define, url*/
define(
[
    'jquery', // For jQuery Added
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote', // For Quote Added
    'ko',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver'
],
function ($, quote, ko, checkoutDataResolver) {
    "use strict";
    var shippingRates = ko.observableArray([]);
    return {
        isLoading: ko.observable(false),
        /**
         * Set shipping rates
         *
         * @param ratesData
         */
        setShippingRates: function (ratesData) {
            if (loggedinCustomer == 1) {
                var address = quote.shippingAddress();

                // you can get zipcode of current shipping address here
                var zipcode = (address.postcode);

                // STOP TO REMOVE ERROR MESSAGE FOR DHL IF SG

                shippingRates(ratesData);
                shippingRates.valueHasMutated();
                checkoutDataResolver.resolveShippingRates(ratesData);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Get shipping rates
         *
         * @returns {*}
         */
        getShippingRates: function () {
            return shippingRates;
        }
    };
  }
);
```

And run setup:upgrade, setup:static-content:deploy commands

Comment: got an error like

Uncaught SyntaxError: In strict mode code, functions can only be declared at top level or inside a block.
console-output-handler.js:34 [2019-02-07 02:59:26] [ERROR] Failed to load the "Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping" component.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this way.

```
protected $_checkoutSession;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $_checkoutSession
    ) {
    $this->_checkoutSession = $_checkoutSession;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
  $postCode = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()-getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();

}
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i have tried this but it gives only postcode of default shipping address. If we select another shipping address then also it gives the default one.

Comment: Ok let me check

Answer (score 2):

Define cart model in helper class & put this below code in it.
Call it in your `observer` or `plugin` method it will give you latest pincode.

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
    ) {
    $this->cart = $cart;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getPostcode(){
   $this->cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getPostcode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get address object of selected shipping address from `default.js` located in this location

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.js
```

there is one function `initObservable` in this function you will get shipping address object of selected shipping address.

Comment: In this "initObservable" function the " shipping address object" gets null , just after adding new billing address.